# Using Dirac's theorem show if $G$ is a simple graph with $|V(G)|=\nu=2k$ and $\frac \nu 2 + 1\le \delta$ then $G$ has a 3-factor.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I got stuck on the connection between Hamiltonian circles and       $k$-factors,
can someone show me how one can find such a connection to get along with the problem?

**Wikipedia's definitions:**
In graph theory, a **factor** of a graph $G$ is a spanning subgraph, i.e., a subgraph that has the same vertex set as $G$. A **$k$-factor** of a graph is a spanning $k$-regular subgraph, and a $k$-factorization partitions the edges of the graph into disjoint $k$-factors. If such a factorization exists we call G, a **$k$-factorable** graph.

**Dirac's theorem:**
A $\nu$-vertex graph in which $\nu\ge 3$ each vertex has degree at least $\frac\nu2$ is Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dirac's theorem on the graph to extract a hamiltonian cycle. Number the edges of the cycle and remove the even ones.

We now have a graph $G'$ which has minimmum degree at least $\nu/2$. So we can extract a hamiltonian cycle from $G'$.

The $3$-factor we need consists of the new hamiltonian cycle, plus the edges we had originally deleted from $G$.